# C equivalent to c++ cin.peek()

Tags: c, newline, stdin, cin, peek

What is the equivalent of cin.peek() for C programming? I need to scan files for '/r' and '/r/n' (these are the end of line markers for DOS files) so I need to "peek" ahead to the next character if the current character is a '/r'

Thanks!

Comment: Those are end-of-line markers on modern Windows systems too, not just "old DOS".

Comment: I hope you understand the difference between a forward-slash and a backslash if you want to do character-oriented programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `ungetc()`, which allows you to push characters back (as if they were not already read), when you've peeked at them.

http://www.zyba.com/reference/computing/c/stdio.h/ungetc.php

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to read+`ungetc()`, you could read your file character by character and just skip unnecessary '\r' and/or '\n' or perform any other special handling of those. A trivial state machine can help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
char c;
FILE *fp;
// opening file, etc.
if((c = getc(fp)) == '\r')
    ungetc(c, fp);
```

or:

```
char c;
FILE *fp;
// opening file, etc.
fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
if(c == '\r')
{
    fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&c, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
}
```

if you need to read two values(as "\n\r"), you can use a short for storing it, and the test with it's numeric value